# How to show preview of Cropped image using Jquery 3.5.1.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that crops images before uploading them. However, the code doesn't show the cropped image as it used to unless I replace the JQuery link of `jquery-3.5.1.min.js` with `jquery-3.4.1.slim.js`.

which I have no idea why suddenly now. And unfortunately, I can't replace jquery 3.5.1 min cause I wrote a lot of code based on that all over the site.

Is there any way we can modify the code so that it can work on 3.5.1 min like it used to?

[JS Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/harish3693/9278xcqb/7/) Please note that this fiddle has `jquery-3.4.1.slim.js` in it. so it will work.

**Code goes as:**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.0/cropper.min.css'>

<input type="file" form="feed-post" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="image" onchange="previewFile()" name="image" class="file_image"/>
<input type="hidden" form="feed-post" name="image_cropped" id="image_cropped" />

<div class="img-container" id="some">
  <img id="image_cropped_preview" />
</div>

<a class="salvar post-btn" id="image_crop_btn" type="button" data-ripple="" style="text-align:center;display:none;">Crop the Image</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.0/cropper.js'></script>

<script>
var recorte = $('.img-container > img');
recorte.cropper({
  movable: false,
  zoomable: false,
  rotatable: false,
  scalable: false
});

function previewFile() {
  var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  $("#image_crop_btn").css("display", "block");
  $("#post-btn").css("display", "none");
  $(".attachments-sub").css("display", "none");

  reader.onloadend = function() {
    $('img').show();
    recorte.cropper('replace', reader.result);
    console.log("test");
  }
  if (file) {
    console.log("test2");
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log("test3");
  } else {
    console.log("test4");
    recorte.cropper('replace', '');
    console.log("test5");
  }
}


$('.salvar').click(function() {
  temp = recorte.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL();
  //window.location.href = recorte.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL();
  $("#some").html('<iframe src="' + temp + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
  //window.document.write('<iframe src="' + temp  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  $("#image_cropped").val(temp);
  $("#image_crop_btn").css("display", "none");
});

</script>
```

**Observation:** I noticed what exactly is going wrong, as I upload the image, the iframe body needs to be appended with the image blob link, which is not happening. that's the only issue, the dress looks good.

When I add the blob element through inspect, it shows.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to buddy. JQuery 3.5.1 min is the recent version and the one that works for you is a slim version which includes this iframe body append function. If you want to make it work with jquery 3.5.1, you have to add additional function to do the iframe body blob appending.

Comment: You are wrong bro, we cannot modify anything inside an iframe using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.salvar').click(function() {
  temp = recorte.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL();
  $("#some").html('<img src="' + temp + '" />')
  $("#image_cropped").val(temp);
  $("#image_crop_btn").css("display", "none");
});
```

so, ya, instead of printing the image in an iframe which caused the issue with jquery 3.5.1, I simply used the img tag. should have thought about it long time ago